# what is the difference between os.open and os.fdopen in python

Tags: python

I am really confused when to use `os.open` and when to use `os.fdopen`

I was doing all my work with `os.open` and it worked without any problem but I am not able to understand under what conditions we need `file descriptors` and all other functions like `dup` and `fsync`

Is the `file object` different from `file descriptor`

i mean `f = os.open("file.txt",w)`

Now is f the fileobject or its the filedescriptor?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open), os.open() returns a file descriptor, whereas the builtin open() returns a file object.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You are confusing the built-in `open()` function with `os.open()` provided by the `os` module. They are quite different; `os.open(filename, "w")` is not valid Python (`os.open` accepts integer flags as its second argument), `open(filename, "w")` is.

In short, `open()` creates new file objects, `os.open()` creates OS-level file descriptors, and `os.fdopen()` creates a file object out of a file descriptor.

File descriptors are a low-level facility for working with files directly provided by the operating system kernel. A file descriptor is a small integer that identifies the open file in a table of open files kept by the kernel for each process. A number of system calls accept file descriptors, but they are not convenient to work with, typically requiring fixed-width buffers, multiple retries in certain conditions, and manual error handling.

File objects are Python classes that wrap file descriptors to make working with files more convenient and less error-prone. They provide, for example, error-handling, buffering, line-by-line reading, charset conversions, and are closed when garbage collected.

To recapitulate:

- Built-in `open()` takes a file name and returns a new Python file object. This is what you need in the majority of cases.
- `os.open()` takes a file name and returns a new file descriptor. This file descriptor can be passed to other low-level functions, such as `os.read()` and `os.write()`, or to `os.fdopen()`, as described below. You only need this when writing code that depends on operating-system-dependent APIs, such as using the `O_EXCL` flag to `open(2)`.
- `os.fdopen()` takes an existing file descriptor — typically produced by Unix system calls such as `pipe()` or `dup()`, and builds a Python file object around it. Effectively it converts a file descriptor to a full file object, which is useful when interfacing with C code or with APIs that only create low-level file descriptors.

Built-in `open` can be emulated by combining `os.open()` (to create a file descriptor) and `os.fdopen()` (to wrap it in a file object):

```
# functionally equivalent to open(filename, "r")
f = os.fdopen(os.open(filename, os.O_RDONLY))
```

Comment: you r right , i was confused with `open` and `os.open()`. can you give me some code example where , i can use `fd` to do something not possible by normal `open`. i want to know how this works

Comment: @user1994660 As I said in the answer, you cannot pass `O_EXCL` or other system-specific flags to builtin `open()`. As for `os.fdopen()`, Unix APIs such as `pipe()`, `dup()`, etc. all return file descriptors, not file objects. In that case you'd use `os.fdopen` to convert such descriptors to file objects.

Comment: I have a specific problem:

Actually django is using fdopen while saving uploaded file in NFS which is taking huge time, however inbuilt open is doing it in milliseconds.

I want to know the reason, could you please guide me how to proceed in this quest.

Comment: @Amandeep That sounds like an interesting problem, and material for a separate question.

Comment: In Python 3, `open()` can be passed a file descriptor also.

Comment: @user102008 Thanks for pointing it out. This answer is still technically correct, but shows its age in some places, especially the last paragraph (given the new functionality of `open()`.) I'll consider how to improve it.