# How do I compare two text files from different folders?

Tags: python, arrays, list, text-files

Assume that I have two folders with 1000 text files in them, for example, folder 1 and folder 2.

Those two folders have text files with the same names, for example:

```
folder 1: ab.txt,  bc.txt,  cd.txt, ac.txt, etc. 
folder 2:  ab.txt,  bc.txt,  cd.txt, ac.txt, etc.
```

Each text file contain bunch of numbers. Here is an example of the text inside the text file, for example, ab.txt from folder 1 has:

```
5 0.796 0.440 0.407 0.399
24 0.973 0.185 0.052 0.070
3 0.91 0.11 0.12 0.1
```

and ab.txt from folder 2 has :

```
1 0.8 0.45 0.407 0.499
24 0.973 0.185 0.052 0.070
5 5.91 6.2 2.22 0.2
```

I want to read the text files inside of those two folders and compare the first column of the each pair of text files that has the same name (indicated above). For example, if the first columns of the two text files have different numbers, I want to move those from folder_1 to another folder called "output". Here is what I wrote. I can compare two text files. However, I wonder how do I compare similar text files located in two different folders?

````py
import difflib

with open(r'path to txt file\') as folder_1:
    file_1_text = file_1.readlines()

with open(r'r'path to txt file\'') as folder_2:
    file_2_text = file_2.readlines()

# Find and print the diff:
for line in difflib.unified_diff(
        file_1_text, file_2_text, fromfile='file1.txt',
        tofile='file2.txt', lineterm=''):
    print(line)```
````

Comment: `Difflib` doesn't have a built-in understanding of columns. Sure you could extend `SequenceMatcher` and `Differ` to do it, but that sounds like a lot of work. Just read the file content, use `str.split()` to turn the data into `list`s, and compare the values in the first column of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all files in a folder with `os.listdir()`.

```
folder1_files = os.listdir(folder_path1)
folder2_files = os.listdir(folder_path2)
```

Than you can iterate over both lists and check if the file names are equal.

```
for file1 in folder1_files:
    for file2 in folder2_files:
        if file1 == file2:
            ...
```

Comparing the first line is also not that difficult. Read the lines of both files and check if they are different.

```
file1_path = os.path.join(folder_path1, file1)
file2_path = os.path.join(folder_path2, file2)
file1_file = open(file1_path, 'r')
file2_file = open(file2_path, 'r')
file1_lines = file1_file.readlines()
file2_lines = file2_file.readlines()
if file1_lines[0] != file2_lines[0]:
    ...
```

I would either use `shutil.move` or `shutil.copy` to move/copy the files.

```
shutil.copy(file1_path, "output/" + file1)
```

Closing the file descriptors

### Note

---

The Term "file descriptor" might Not be 100% accurate in this context because `open()` creates a file object not a file descriptor. The basis of a file object is a file descriptor so `file.close()` is closing the file descriptor but I still think you can't say it like that. Read more here: [what is the difference between os.open and os.fdopen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039528/what-is-the-difference-between-os-open-and-os-fdopen-in-python)

---

```
file1_file.close()
file2_file.close()
```

All together in a function:

```
def compare_files(folder_path1, folder_path2):
    import os
    import shutil
    folder1_files = os.listdir(folder_path1)
    folder2_files = os.listdir(folder_path2)
    for file1 in folder1_files:
        for file2 in folder2_files:
            if file1 == file2:
                file1_path = os.path.join(folder_path1, file1)
                file2_path = os.path.join(folder_path2, file2)
                file1_file = open(file1_path, 'r')
                file2_file = open(file2_path, 'r')
                file1_lines = file1_file.readlines()
                file2_lines = file2_file.readlines()
                output_path = "output"
                if not os.path.exists(output_path):
                    os.makedirs(output_path)
                if file1_lines[0] != file2_lines[0]:
                    shutil.copy(file1_path, output_path + "/" + file1)
                file1_file.close()
                file2_file.close()

compare_files("folder1", "folder2")
```

if you want to compare the numbers and e.g. `1` should be the same as `1.0` you can do the following.

```
l1 = file1_lines[0].split()
l2 = file2_lines[0].split()
for i in range(len(l1 if len(l1) < len(l2) else l2)):
    if float(l1[i]) != float(l2[i]):
        output_path = "output"
        if not os.path.exists(output_path):
            os.makedirs(output_path)
        shutil.copy(file1_path, output_path)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, I try to use ```shutil.move``` to move files from the old folder to the new folder. But that does not work. It gives an error saying ```The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: ``` I am not sure why is that happening. Could you please advise?

Comment: @Happypumpkinpm It works for me. But I can think two possibilitys why this error is raised. It is most likely opened by an text editor, in this case close the editor and try again. It is very unlikely but maybe in your case you need to call `file1_file.close()` and `file2_file.close()` befor calling `shutil.move()`. So move the two lines before `if not os.path.exists(output_path):` and try again